# how to trigger a method after a background upload is finished?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I need my application to encrypt a text file and save it to local storage after downloading it using the [flutter uploader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_uploader).
so how can I use my dart function that encrypts and save files?

Answer (score -1):

you can add `then` like this:

```
final uploader = FlutterUploader();

    final taskId = await uploader.enqueue(
        url: "your upload link", 
        method: UploadMethod.POST, 
        headers: {"apikey": "api_123456", "userkey": "userkey_123456"},
        data: {"name": "john"}, 
        showNotification: false, 
        tag: "upload 1").then( (data)
        {
          //your code here
        }
    );
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it did not help because .then called after enqueue finished not after the upload finish